# What is the python equivalent of JavaScript's Array.prototype.find?

Tags: python, find

I'm looking for something like: `find(pred, iter)` in python

```
obj = { 
         "foo_list": [ 
           {"name": "aaaa", "id": 111},
           {"name": "bbbb", "id": 222},
           {"name": "cccc", "id": 333}
         ]
}
```

How to:
   `find(lambda x: x.get("name") == "bbbb", obj.get("foo_list", []))`

Comment: Do you want to find all matching values or just the first?

Comment: @PeterWood just the first

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
def find(pred, iterable):
  for element in iterable:
      if pred(element):
          return element
  return None

# usage:
find(lambda x: x.get("name") == "bbbb", obj.get("foo_list", []))
```

Comment: Worth mentioning that different from the `filter()` function, this approach will stop iterating over the array once the element is found 

Comment: @Jonathan Its not a problem, cause filter returns a generator. So using it will still effective.
Here are the results: https://i.imgur.com/tEImOFd.png

Answer (score 35):

[`Array.prototype.find()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) returns the first matching element in an array, given a predicate function, or `undefined` when there is no match.

Python has the [`filter()` function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#filter), which filters an iterable on a predicate, and [`next()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#next), which produces the first element of an iterable or an optional default. Combining these give you the equivalent:

```
next(filter(pred, iter), None)
```

where `pred` is a callable that returns `True` when an element matches the search criteria.

Demo:

```
>>> iterable = [42, 81, 117]
>>> parity_odd = lambda v: v % 2 == 1
>>> next(filter(parity_odd, iterable), None)
81
>>> iterable = [42, 2, 4]
>>> next(filter(parity_odd, iterable), None) is None
True
```

If you remove the second argument to `next()`, a `StopIteration` exception is raised when there is no matching element.

Answer (score 5):

python:filter == js.findAll

```
    bb = list(filter(lambda item: item.get("name") == "bbbb", list))
    bb[0]
```

find the object in a object list by attribute value